# nginx-upload-module for large amount of small size data

Tags: java, performance, nginx, high-load

Quick question, I have lost of average 2-3k data to upload, may be 2000 request/second, two options:

1. Use nginx-upload-module to save file to disk and then read file in java
2. Just send all data to java directly, java save data to file if cannot process in time

which one should I use and why?

Thanks in advance!